# Getting below error while doing scd2 in snowflake using merge statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My statement:

```
insert into target_scd2
select id,name,flag from (
  merge into target_scd2 as t
  using source as s
     on t.id=s.id
  when matched and t.name <> s.name then
       update set flag='N'
  when not matched then
       insert values(s.id,s.name,'Y') 
  OUTPUT $Action action_flag,s.id,s.name,'Y'
  ) as merge_out 
where merge_out.action_flag='UPDATE';
```

I am getting below error while executed the above statement:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 0 unexpected 'merge'. syntax error line 9 at position 29 unexpected ')'.

Can you please help what can be the issue

Comment: Here's the snowflake `merge` doco. It is not valid snowflake syntax. You'll need to change it to valid snowflake syntax, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

Answer (score 4):

The pattern presented here is called: **"INSERT over DML"** and it is SQL Server specific.

More info: [D. Inserting the results of the MERGE statement into another table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-inserting-the-results-of-the-merge-statement-into-another-table)

---

> *Can you please help what can be the issue*

a) Using merge as subquery of INSERT SELECT

b) OUTPUT/(RETURNING) clause support

The Snowflake documentation of [MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html).